# Different extensions of linear operators on euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

In the euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, it's possible to find a linear subspace $Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and a linear and bounded operator $l \in Y'$ such that $l$ has two different extensions $T_1, T_2$ in the dual of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $ \left\|{T_1}\right\|= \left\|{T_2}\right\|= \left\|{l}\right\|$? I think that it's possible if $Y$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I could not find some example.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{R}^n = Y \oplus Y^{\perp}$.

Comment: Previously, I considered this idea, but the problem is that the norms of the three operators must be equal. I considered $n=2$, but I can work for some $n>2$.

Comment: Consider also that $(Y^{\perp})' = (Y')^{\perp}$.